# Why are java files compiled to several locations in java project

Tags: java, apache, class, compilation

when I compile a java project, apparently its class file was compiled at the 1st link, but there are also same classes compiled at 2nd link, so my question is why there are 2 locations where my classes are compiled to?

Source:

```
D:\dev\workspace\WebSlip\src\jp\ac\u-tokyo\examslip\pdf\ExamSlipTemplate.java
```

Destination of build classes:

```
D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\WebSlip\WEB-INF\classes\jp\ac\u-tokyo\examslip\pdf\ExamSlipTemplate.class
```

D:\dev\workspace\WebSlip\build\classes\jp\ac\u-tokyo\examslip\pdf\ExamSlipTemplate.class

Extra:
I have added this in later after this question was posted, the changes I made
does not take effect may and I have search online I came across articles that 
ask me to delete _java.class file, does this means delete the compiled class file at both the build and deploy location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you chose "deploy on server", building your application results in both compiling your code and deploying it on to your server. This is your build location :

```
D:\dev\workspace\WebSlip\build\classes\jp\ac\u-tokyo\examslip\pdf\ExamSlipTemplate.class
```

And this one is your deployment location :

```
D:\dev\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\WebSlip\WEB-INF\classes\jp\ac\u-tokyo\examslip\pdf\ExamSlipTemplate.class
```

You can manage this property from project properties.